# Angular ng-confirm-click doesn't work

Tags: angularjs

Could you please explain why my `ng-confirm-click` doesn't work?

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-init="show=true;">
  <p >Hello {{name}}!</p>
  <button ng-show="show" confirmed-click="changes();show=false;" ng-confirm-click="Confirm change?">change</button>
</div>
```

I need to hide the button.

Here the example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app = "plunker">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-init="show=true;">
      <p >Hello {{name}}!</p>
      <button ng-show="show" confirmed-click="changes();show=false;" ng-confirm-click="Confirm change?">change</button>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: i edited the example n it works

Answer (score 2):

Try this working code,

Inside html:

```
  <div ng-confirm-click="Are you sure to delete this product ?" confirmed-click="deletePost(data.postId)"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></div>
```

In app.js file, put the below code(without any change):

```
app.directive('ngConfirmClick', [
    function(){
        return {
            link: function (scope, element, attr) {
                var msg = attr.ngConfirmClick || "Are you sure?";
                var clickAction = attr.confirmedClick;
                element.bind('click',function (event) {
                    if ( window.confirm(msg) ) {
                        scope.$eval(clickAction)
                    }
                });
            }
        };
}])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `scope.$apply` instead of `scope.$eval` and remove unnecessary `scope.$apply` from controller.

From documentation:

> This use of $eval: scope.$eval() seems to be deprecated in favor of scope.$apply to execute a function that uses and modifies the scope, and update the view later.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qdkiJXD5ygc9HsB1qQLU?p=preview)